# Is this the correct way of using Variational Principle (Minimization Principle)?

Tags: calculus, optimization, calculus-of-variations

I am constructing a smooth function $f(x)\equiv f(u(x),v(x))$, such that $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are some trial parameters. I have the following integral
$$G=\int_{x_i}^{x_f} f(u(x),v(x)) \mathrm{d}x.$$
My aim: To find the trial functions $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ using the stationary principle. Therefore, essentially I want $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ to be such that $G$ is minimum.

My question: Am I allowed to use: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=0$$ to solve for $u(x)$ and $v(x)$?

Comment: You don't have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$, you essentially have $\frac{\partial G}{\partial u}$. But that derivative is different from familiar derivatives, because it is a derivative with respect to a function. You also should say something about constraints on $u$ and $v$. (You *also* needn't think of $u,v$ as separate variables, they can be joined together into a single vector-valued function of $x$.)

Comment: Well, the integral is supposed to be definite (sorry for the confusion, I have corrected it), and therefore, G is merely some constant. Thus, it does not make sense to have $\partial G/\partial u$.

Comment: Sure it does; $G$ is a function of the *functions* $u,v$, which for minimization purposes should be considered to be variables themselves.

Comment: $u$ is a function of $x$, and once you integrate over $x$, there is no information of $u$ that is left anymore. So, I am not sure how you could say $G$ is a function of $u, v$.

Comment: If I take $u(x)=x$ I get a different value of $G$ than if I took $u(x)=x^2$ (for "typical" choices of $f$).

Comment: As for the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange-like equation, you take $G(g)=\int_a^b f(g(x)) dx$. Consider $h(x)=g(x)+\epsilon a(x)$ where we assume $a$ is bounded and $h$ is admissible. Then $G(h) = G(g)+\epsilon \int_a^b f'(g(x)) a(x) dx + o(\epsilon)$. This means that the functional derivative of $G$ is the linear map $a \mapsto \int_a^b f'(g(x)) a(x) dx$. For this to vanish means that $f'(g(x))$ must be $L^2$-perpendicular to all admissible perturbations $a$. With no constraints this means that you must have $f'(g(x))=0$ for every $x$; with constraints you can have a nontrivial situation.

Comment: Exactly, but that just means that $G$ depends on the functional form of $u(x)$, it does not mean that $G$ is a "function" of $u(x)$. Therefore, the exact problem I am posing is how should I choose $u(x)$ such that $G$ is minimum.

Comment: Your previous answer would mean that my suggestion in the originial question of setting $f'(u(x))=f'(g(x))=0$ is correct, I guess.

Comment: You misunderstand, I chose my notation carefully: $G$ is a function of the *function* $u$. You are correct that it does not make sense to speak of $G$ depending on an individual value of $u(x)$, but it does make sense to speak of $G$ being a function of the *function* $u$. This is in fact the same thing as saying that $G$ depends on the functional form of $u$, as you put it.

Comment: Anyway, with no constraints the only possible minimizer is a function $g$ such that $f'(g(x))=0$ for every $x$. Typically these problems are posed with constraints (for example, in the Euler-Lagrange scenario we require $q(a)$ and $q(b)$ to have particular values).

Comment: Could you elaborate what happens with additional constraint?

Comment: With constraints on $g$, the admissible perturbations are restricted, which means the optimality requirement changes. One way that this happens that you have probably seen before is with Lagrange multipliers: instead of needing $\nabla f = 0$ you merely wind up needing $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$, which is a weaker requirement (in the sense that this holds by default if $\nabla f = 0$). A similar effect occurs in the calculus of variations. But I can't really give a generic description, I'd need to know what sort of constraints you're talking about.

Comment: So, is there any specific equation would you use if you have constraint?

Comment: The most commonly used equation of this sort is the Euler-Lagrange equation, but the scenario where it is derived is a bit different. You have boundary value constraints and the Lagrangian ($f$ in your notation) depends both on $q(x)$ and on $q'(x)$.